# Quando optar por Composables em detrimento de Renderless Components no Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Recentemente, ao me aprofundar no Vue.js 3, deparei-me com os conceitos de Composables e Renderless Components.

Entendi que ambos visam a desacoplar lógica e apresentação, mas me surgiu a dúvida: quais são as situações ou critérios que determinam a escolha entre um Composable e um Renderless Component?

Considerando que suas finalidades se assemelham na reutilização e encapsulamento da lógica, gostaria de compreender melhor quando um é mais indicado que o outro.

Comment: **Observação do usuário:** *Quero muito pegar as manhas para fazer escolhas mais assertivas nos meus projetos.*